# Clarification for locating .RDS OAuth tokens generated by `gargle` package

Tags: r, google-sheets, rstudio

Not strictly an RStudio question but the relevant packages are maintained by this community I think.

Apologies for not providing a working example of the problem. The question pertains to use within a container, and I am not sure if an example will provide clarity. :|

I am reading this about non-interactive authentication to google, for googlesheets/googledrive (either will do).
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gargle/vignettes/non-interactive-auth.html
I am confused by the following:

> If you know the filepath to the token you want to use, you could use readRDS() to read it and provide as the token argument to the wrapper’s auth function.
>
> How would you know this filepath? That requires some attention to the location of gargle’s OAuth token cache folder, which is described in the next section.

I can't find a clear description in this or the linked documents of where to find the .RDS file.

My use-case is to read or download a googlesheet (via googlesheets or googledrive packages) within a docker package.

I was previously doing this just fine with the old token setup, before google made the changes their side.

Also I have no problem running non-interactively within a scrip on my machine, using `httr::oauth_app` and `drive_auth_configure`, then `drive_auth` as described in the above link.

I am just not clear as to how I can locate the .RDS file from the above documentation.

If you could give a brief description, or if you were so kind as to provide a link to other documents, or sections of the above that I have overlooked or misunderstood I would be very grateful.

Thank you!

Simon